# crypt sem o uso do salt

Tags: php, senhas, salt

Existe um sistema em PHP que não foi desenvolvido por mim, ele usa `crypt` para criptografar a senha do usuário, assim:

```
$senha = crypt($senha);
```

Com a atualização do PHP no servidor, o `crypt` está pedindo um `salt` na hora de criar a senha de novos usuários.

O problema é que já existem mais de 10 mil usuários cadastrados no sistema sem salt. Se eu começar a incluir agora o salt, terei problemas com o login dos usuários antigos, pois eles não tem salt.

O que fazer?

Comment: Pode postar o trecho do código?

Comment: Conforme documentação do PHP o `salt é uma string opcional para base da encriptação. Se não fornecido, será gerado randomicamente pelo PHP cada vez que chamar esta função.`